# Cannot push to github repo

Tags: git, version-control, github, push

My repo: https://shadyabhi@github.com/shadyabhi/learnajax.git

```
shadyabhi@archlinux-N210 ~/github/learnajax $ cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://shadyabhi@github.com/shadyabhi/learnajax.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
shadyabhi@archlinux-N210 ~/github/learnajax $ git config -l
user.name=shadyabhi
user.email=abhijeet.1989@gmail.com
merge.tool=vimdiff
github.token=1095de7027bVVVV01cfAAAAAa5fc8f6
color.ui=auto
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://shadyabhi@github.com/shadyabhi/learnajax.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
shadyabhi@archlinux-N210 ~/github/learnajax $ git push -u origin master
Password: 
fatal: Authentication failed
shadyabhi@archlinux-N210 ~/github/learnajax $
```

Now, I cant push into my repo. I have checked the github.token its the same as my Account Settings. Ofcoarse, I am entering the right password but I get this error.

Comment: Have you tried using SSH keys?

Comment: I have it blocked at my place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is some issue (if using https) if username contains "some" special characters.

Comment: Use mypass2011^@: as your password and you will know it that you wont be able to push

Comment: Did you contact GitHub about that? Seems like the bug is still there.

Comment: I recently changed my github account password to contain '.' and '!' characters and https authentication stopped working. This is dumb.

Comment: In my case in username was wrong. just first letter capital instead of small.

Answer (score 74):

I was having a similar issue pushing my origin with the correct user and password. It turned out that I had turned on 2-factor Authentication and had forgotten. If you have 2-factor Authentication enabled you will need to create an application specific password to push your repo. https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

Comment: That's the ticket. Apparently though once you enable 2-factor auth it no long allows key based auth (I guess that makes sense as it is only one factor)

Comment: Just in case it's not clear, the token that is generated here needs to be used in lieu of your password.

Comment: I got the access token, now what?

Comment: @Marian07: I know I'm late to respond but in case you didn't find the answer, you have to supply the personal access token in place of your password. For example, if, from the command line, you are doing "git push origin master", when you are asked to supply your password for GitHub, instead supply the personal access token that was generated.

Answer (score 6):

As I understand it, `github.token` (and `github.user`) aren't used by git HTTP transport - they're only there for other tools that use GitHub's API, [such as GitX and GitNub](https://github.com/blog/180-local-github-config).

I think the "Authentication failed" error *must* be due to you entering the wrong password.  (This should be your GitHub password rather than the password to your SSH private key.)

Comment: I just discovered that if your pass is "mypass2011^@:", I cant git push using https. Sounds wierd, but can anyone confirm?

Comment: I had a similar problem; it didn't occur to me that using the SSH password wouldn't work for HTTPS (though, in hindsight, its absolutely obvious).  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 6):

I have hit the same problem just now.  Apparently, when you use git in command line, it wants you to enter the access token instead of password.  This is really weird, but it works.

```
$ git push origin HEAD
Username for 'https://github.com':        <--- your username here
Password for 'https://t7ko@github.com':   <--- access token here O_O
```

PS: This is the instruction on creating token: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use

Answer (score 2):

I had just same problem as previously described. Passwords with `#`, `¤` or `"` didn't seem to work, whatever I tried.

Seems to be more or less similar problem as with Microsoft Office 365 portal, where you can't use ex. `¤` character in password, if you are going to use mobile devices as well.

Github login works fine with all passwords, in web... but using whatever client, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If your password contains special characters, `git push` won't work in Terminal.  My workaround is open up `emacs` and do `git push` inside `eshell`.

Comment: Do you have idea why is that?

Comment: failed for me :( but thanks for letting me know eshell exists!

Answer (score 1):

if your username or password has special characters, you can replace it with the encoded 
for example, if your password is "test@2010", you will write it as "test%402010" and the config command will be like this
`git config remote.origin.url https://{username}:test%402010@github.com/{repo_username}/{repo_name}.git`