# Error message to upload from Source Tree 3 to GitHub and Bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

**Background**

- macOS 10.12
- SourceTree 3
- GitHub
- Bitbucket
- Django Project

**What I have Done**

- Filenames are changed for privacy reasons
- I wanted to push a previously committed version to GitHub than to Bitbucket
- This worked for a long while but since this new sticking out baranch this doesent woks and I get this error message (this sticking out RED branch can and should be deleted)
- I have rebased before to the commit just before that sticking out branch by `git reset --hard COMITIDNAME`

[image]
[image]

**Pop up ERROR message**

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false -c credential.helper=sourcetree push -v --tags --set-upstream origin refs/heads/HEAD:refs/heads/HEAD 
Pushing to https://github.com/myusernameongithub/myprojectnameongithub.git
error: src refspec refs/heads/HEAD does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusernameongithub/myprojectnameongithub.git'
Completed with errors, see above
```

**Goal**

- I want to keep only 1 tag and move forward with that, use that in the future to upload in the future to both GitHub and Bitbucket (or if needed because of the 2 git storage places that minimum amount of more tags)
- Being able to upload my gits to Github and Bitbucket

**What I have tried/looked up**

- [Cannot push to github repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486143/cannot-push-to-github-repo)
- [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

- Right click on the head tag that you can see on the 1st picture
- chose branch
- chose Delete branches delete all the branches you don't want to have (it is important that remote beaches are added that are up in your server + branches that you keep locally, so pay attention what is what)
- than `git reset --hard COMMIT_NEMUR_AND_LETTERS` this jumps you back to that given branch and deletes everything above it.